# Not able to Access Billing info using Azure CLI

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-billing-api

I created a service principal using rbac and using the subscription id and I was able to login and all CLI calls with Azure using this sp and this login

(creating SP
az ad sp create-for-rbac -n "AppName1" --role contributor --scopes /subscriptions//resourceGroups/)

But when I call for billing info as:
az consumption usage list --subscription 
Unauthorized. Request ID:

I am not sure what authentication permission scope to add to enable this. Tried too many things and somehow I feel I am not in the right direction. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you add the Billing Reader role to the Service Principal?

Answer (score 1):

Did you login with the service principle using the following command before hitting the billing/usage?

`az login --service-principal -u <app-url> -p <password-or-cert> --tenant <tenant>`

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is that you assigned the “contributor” role at the resource group level and then trying to access a subscription level resource. Since you don’t have permission for that, you’re getting this “Unauthorized” error.

To fix this, please try to assign the “contributor” role at the subscription level for this service principal.

Comment: Yes, this fixed the issue. Needed to add the Role Contributor for the SP also. Thanks